Implementation of interceptors in angular 17
how do I inject an interceptor to an application generated as a modular app in angular 17? I mean the one generated with the --standalone argument?
I tried injecting it as [provideHttpClient(withInterceptors([AuthInterceptor]))] without success. The application gets into an infinite loop.

It would be helpful if you could provide some information of what type of interceptor you are using.
In the Angular 17 standalone configuration, you need to configure the providers array in app.config.ts file.  The exact way to provide them depends on if it is functional or class interceptor.
If it is the newer functional interceptors introduced in Angular 15, you should provide it the way you suggest in your question.  You can identify if you are using funtional interceptors as it will implement the HttpInterceptorFn interface.
Provide functional interceptors like this:
providers: [
   provideHttpClient(withInterceptors([authenticationInterceptor]))
]

If you are using the older class-based interceptor then you should continue to provide it in the traditional way.
Provide class-based interceptors like this::
providers: [
    provideHttpClient(withInterceptorsFromDi())
]

